If a toilet moves a little because it was loose can you just move it back or do you need to replace the wax ring?
A painter spun my toilet a few degrees. I guess the bolts were loose. I showed him and he just spun it back as it was. But I suspect that that movement would have broken the seal with the wax ring. The painter showed me it wasn't leaking and says it's fine. Does it need a new wax ring?
I'm assuming it probably does need a new wax ring. I'm looking for an answer from someone who knows, not someone who'll just type "yes", just to be on the safe side. If yes, I have to point the finger at my painter and make him do it. I don't want to do that just to be on the safe side.

I have to point the finger at my painter ... not the painter's fault that you have a loose toilet

@jsotola Yeah, I told him if it needs to be replaced he can charge me a little. It was loose, that doesn't mean he had to move it like that. (Unless he loosened it himself, but I'll never know.)

why would the painter charge you for moving the toilet?

Noone will know for sure. There are many different types of wax rings, flange seals. The fact that the toilet was easily moved and not caulked in the first place would steer away from the painter's fault. All in all, the ring should be replaced. They are not reuseable and once moved from the original "press to fit", they won't reseal.

Whether or not you should caulk a toilet at all is a matter of some debate. I'm off the opinion that you should not caulk a toilet

@Matthew That's a popular opinion.  I've always caulked around the toilet but left an inch or two open in the back in case there was a leak you would notice it.  Plus it just makes the installation look neater if the tiles or floor are a bit off.

You are searching for a definitive answer. It would not be prudent to give a definitive answer since there are factors that are unknown.
Those being;
What type of seal the toilet has?  Some are reusable and turning would not be an issue. You could just snug the toilet back down.
Was the toilet loose to begin with, or did the painter use force to move it and possibly break the flange the bolts hold to.  In that case the flange would need to be repaired for the toilet to be properly mounted.
If there is a wax seal, is there enough wax undisturbed to provide a proper seal.
The answers to these questions are unknown. Therefore there is no possibility of giving you a definitive answer.
A suggestion would be to place some toilet paper flat on the floor and try to slide it under the toilet base. Flush the toilet and see if the paper becomes damp.  Try this in multiple places around the base. Flush multiple times.
If the toilet paper remains dry in all tests, you can conclude that the toilet is not leaking water currently.  However this does not dismiss the possibility that a leak could develop in the near future.  It is for this reason that best practice would suggest that the toilet be removed for inspection of the flange and the seal be replaced so there may be reasonable expectation for proper performance going forward.  This is a choice you must make.
Regarding sealing a toilet to the floor, this is a regional thing. In my location it is required by code. In other locations it is simply a preference.

Wax rings are single use only.  Once the toilet is moved, the seal is broken.
Wax rings should only leak when the toilet is flushed, so not leaking without a flush is not a good test.
The toilet bolts being loose enough to allow movement is not a good sign the wax ring was not already broken/leaking before the painter moved it.  Tight enough bolts should require some force to move the toilet.
It might be only a minor drip leak now.
